# Python-Twitter and access_token and access_token_secret

Tags: python, twitter

I'm trying to use python-twitter to read my twitter feed and display it on my website. Everything worked fine until twitter required oAuth. I'm in the process of updating by scripts, but the python-twitter docs call for this:

```
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='consumer_key', consumer_secret='consumer_secret', access_token_key='access_token', access_token_secret='access_token_secret')
```

I created an Twitter App (not sure of that is what I was supposed to do) and I have the `consumer_key` and the `consumer_secret`, but I don't know where to find the `access_token` or the `access_token_secret`. Am I missing something obvious?

I just need to read my twitter feed. I don't need to post to it.

Comment: Never mind, I was missing something obvious. You go to the oAuth Tool tab and they are there.

Comment: The OP found the answer after posting question.

Comment: @RogerGilbrat you can [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), accept your answer and then close it rather than leaving it open.

Comment: @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy Answering your own question is perfectly valid.  The OP sorting it out on their own does not make the post off-topic.

Comment: @tcaswell i am retracting it.

Answer (score 1):

I was missing something obvious. You go to the oAuth Tools tab on the twitter dev site and you can find the `access_token` and the `access_token_secret`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the OAuth tools tab on the twitter app site, and you can see the Keys and Access Tokens, the section below the `Consumer Key (API Key)` and `Consumer Secret (API Secret)` is empty. You have to generate a Access Token that will generate a `Access Token` and `Access Token Secret`. Please do not share the values with anyone.

Hope this helps.